# Returning promises won't work for AWS SDK

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, promise, aws-sdk

I've created an API which calls get cloudWatch AWS API and gives back datapoints that can be graphed on my app. I have separate routes for each package (as shown in the routing code below). This API uses REST MVC Method.

So a couple things I'm doing with my function.

1. Reading in EC2 Instance data from a SQLite3 database to grab
   information about a running instance (IP, instance_id,
   instance_launchtime) so that I can put it in the parameters required
   for the getMetricStatistics API from the AWS SDK.
2. This data from step1 is then put into an array of parameters (3 that respond with 3 different metric datapoints). This loops through each parameter, inserting it into the getMetricStatistics API (ONE BY ONE SINCE getMetricStatistics doesn't accept multiple metrics at once) to grab data points for that instance and push them to an array.

For the database is async I believe, that is why I've attached a promise to it. **When I load in the endpoint into my browser, it just keeps loading and won't show any data. When I do refresh the page, however, it shows all the results correctly...**

This is my controller for the API:

```
// Return results sent from Cloud Watch API
const InsightModel = require('../models/insight.model.js');
const cloudWatch = InsightModel.cloudWatch;
const CWParams = InsightModel.CWParams;
const packageById = InsightModel.packageById;

let cpuUtilParam;
let cpuCBParam;
let cpuCUParam;
let insightParams = [];
let metricResults = [];
exports.getAnalytics = (req, res) => {
  const currentDate = new Date().toISOString();
  let promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    packageById(req.params.packageKey, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(
          res.status(500).send({
            message:
              err.message ||
              'Error while getting the insight configuration data.',
          })
        );
      } else {
        cpuUtilParam = new CWParams(
          currentDate,
          'CPUUtilization',
          'AWS/EC2',
          data[0].launch_time,
          data[0].instance_id
        );
        cpuCBParam = new CWParams(
          currentDate,
          'CPUCreditBalance',
          'AWS/EC2',
          data[0].launch_time,
          data[0].instance_id
        );
        cpuCUParam = new CWParams(
          currentDate,
          'CPUCreditUsage',
          'AWS/EC2',
          data[0].launch_time,
          data[0].instance_id
        );
        insightParams = [cpuUtilParam, cpuCBParam, cpuCUParam];
          resolve(insightParams);
      }
    });
  })
  let promise2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    insightParams.forEach(metric => {
      cloudWatch.getMetricStatistics(metric, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
          reject(
            res.status(500).send({
              messaage:
                err.message ||
                'Error occured while running cloudWatch getMetricStatistcs API: ',
            })
          );
        } else {
          metricResults.push(data);
          if (metricResults.length === insightParams.length)
            resolve(metricResults);
        }
      });
    });
  });

  Promise.all([promise1, promise2])
    .then(metricResults => {
      res.send(metricResults);
      console.log('AWS CW API successful');
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send({
        messaage:
          err.message ||
          'Error occured while reading in a promise from cloudWatch getMetricStatistcs API: ',
      })
    });
  metricResults = [];
};
```

The model for the API:

```
// Call AWS Cost Explorer API
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const config = require('./AWSconfig');
const database = require('./db');

const insightdb = database.insightdb;

AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: config.accessKeyId,
  secretAccessKey: config.secretAccessKey,
  region: config.region,
});

//Linking AWS CloudWatch Service
var cloudWatch = new AWS.CloudWatch();

const packageById = (packageId, callback) => {
  insightdb.all(
    'SELECT * FROM ec2Instance WHERE package_id == ?',
    packageId,
    (err, rows) => {
      if (err) {
        callback(err, null);
      } else {
        callback(null, rows);
      }
    }
  );
};

// Parameter class to feed into the CloudWatch getMetricStatistics function
const CWParams = function(reqDate, metricName,service,launchTime,instanceId) {
  (this.EndTime = reqDate) /* required */,
    (this.MetricName = metricName) /* required */,
    (this.Namespace = service) /* required */,
    (this.Period = 3600) /* required */,
    (this.StartTime = launchTime) /* ${createDate}`, required */,
    (this.Dimensions = [
      {
        Name: 'InstanceId' /* required */,
        Value: instanceId /* required */,
      },
    ]),
    (this.Statistics = ['Maximum']);
};

//Exports variables to the controller (so they can be re-used)
module.exports = { cloudWatch, CWParams, packageById };
```

The route for the API:

```
module.exports = app => {
  const insight = require('../controllers/insight.controller.js');
  app.get('/insights/aws/:packageKey', insight.getAnalytics);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it stands, in the second Promise constructor, insightParams is guaranteed not to have been composed yet because `insightParams = [.....]` is in a callback that is called asynchronously. Therefore, the program flow needs to ensure all the "promise2" stuff happens only after "promise1" is fulfilled.

Things become a lot simpler in the higher level code if asynchronous functions are "promisified" at the lowest possible level. So do two things in the model:

- Promisify `cloudWatch.getMetricStatistics()`
- Write packageById() to return `Promise` rather than accepting a callback.

The model thus becomes:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk'); // no change
const config = require('./AWSconfig'); // no change
const database = require('./db'); // no change

const insightdb = database.insightdb; // no change

AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: config.accessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: config.secretAccessKey,
    region: config.region
}); // no change

var cloudWatch = new AWS.CloudWatch(); // no change

// Promisify cloudWatch.getMetricStatistics() as  cloudWatch.getMetricStatisticsAsync().
cloudWatch.getMetricStatisticsAsync = (metric) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        cloudWatch.getMetricStatistics(metric, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                if(!err.message) { // Probably not necessary but here goes ...
                    err.message = 'Error occured while running cloudWatch getMetricStatistcs API: ';
                }
                reject(err); // (very necessary)
            } else {
                resolve(data);
            }
        });
    });
};

// Ensure that packageById() returns Promise rather than accepting a callback.
const packageById = (packageId) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        insightdb.all('SELECT * FROM ec2Instance WHERE package_id == ?', packageId, (err, rows) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(rows);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Now `getAnalytics()` can be written like this:

```
exports.getAnalytics = (req, res) => {
    packageById(req.params.packageKey)
    .then(data => {
        const currentDate = new Date().toISOString();
        let insightParams = [
            new CWParams(currentDate, 'CPUUtilization', 'AWS/EC2', data[0].launch_time, data[0].instance_id),
            new CWParams(currentDate, 'CPUCreditBalance', 'AWS/EC2', data[0].launch_time, data[0].instance_id),
            new CWParams(currentDate, 'CPUCreditUsage', 'AWS/EC2', data[0].launch_time, data[0].instance_id)
        ];
        // Composition of `insightParams` is synchronous so you can continue 
        // with the `cloudWatch.getMetricStatisticsAsync()` stuff inside the same .then().
        return Promise.all(insightParams.map(metric => cloudWatch.getMetricStatisticsAsync(metric))); // Simple because of the Promisification above.
    }, err => {
        // This callback handles error from packageById() only,
        // and is probably unnecessary but here goes ...
        if(!err.message) {
            err.message = 'Error while getting the insight configuration data.';
        }
        throw err;
    })
    .then(metricResults => {
        res.send(metricResults);
        console.log('AWS CW API successful');
    })
    .catch(err => {
        // Any async error arising above will drop through to here.
        res.status(500).send({
            'message': err.message
        }));
    });
};
```

Note that multiple catches each with `res.status(500).send()` are not necessary. Error propagation down the Promise chain allows a single, terminal `.catch()`

Comment: This is the response I get back:
{
    "message": "data is not defined"
}

Comment: Edited - try again.

Comment: And another minor edit. `insightParams` wasn't declared.

Comment: Also, I don't completely understand this code (although it's beautiful). What's the process flow (like in the controller). Does the packageById promise get resolved first? If so, how come you're returning a Promise.all at the end and passing in the map/getMetricStatisticsAsync. My understanding is Promise.all takes multiple promises in an array and processes them in parallel.

Comment: `packageById()` is called first. When the returned promise resolves, it delivers `data` to the immediately following `then()`. `insightParams.map(metric => cloudWatch.getMetricStatisticsAsync(metric))` maps the `insightParams` array to an array of Promises, which are then aggregated by `Promise.all()`, ie when all the Promises in the array have resolved, `Promise.all()` delivers an array of results to the next `.then()` in the chain where they appear as `metricResults`.